# Regular Expression to match a string of numbers and dash in javascript 

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a string like `2431-72367`, i.e., a string with at least one number before and after the dash and only one dash.

I need to check it in JavaScript. Can anyone give me the regex and explain it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/^\d+-\d+$/` will work.

- `^` signals the begin of the string.
- `\d+` means one or more digits.
- `$` signals the end of the string.

As a result, `/^\d+-\d+$/.test("2431-72367")` returns true.

Answer (score 5):

The regex could be something like this:

```
^\d+-\d+$
```

This means:

```
    ^             Start of string
    \d            Digit
    +             One or more
    -             "-"
    \d            Digit
    +             One or more
    $             End of string
```